# get cookie value which has dynamic name

Tags: nginx

I want to enable caching for logged-in users in nginx:

For example, if the session cookie is named 'JSESSIONID', we can use like this:
proxy_cache_key $proxy_host$request_uri$cookie_jessionid;

Now the problem is if the cookie name is dynamic like:

```
wordpress_logged_in_<randomhash>
```

How can we do it? Maybe we can do it via $http_cookie with the nginx map function? But I don't have any idea to do it.